# FB OpenGraph : Obtaining the privacy level on a Photo object, specifically from Timeline, Profile Picture or Cover Albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

For those specific 'system' albums (Profile Photos, Timeline Photos and Cover Image), a user may specify the privacy level for each photo. This behavior differs from user-created albums, where the privacy of the album dictates the privacy of the photos within.

My objective is to show my user with a list of their public facebook pictures, so they can pick a few for their profile. Those pictures will be shown to anyone, hence why I only want to show pictures that have a scope of "everyone.

For user-created albums, querying the privacy of the album works.

```
me/albums?fields=name,id,privacy

returns:
"data": [
...
{
  "name": "Full Public",
  "id": ...,
  "privacy": "everyone",
},
```

All pictures within this album are safe to show.

But when it comes to, e.g. Profile Picture albums, the privacy is now on a per-photo basis, and the Photo opengraph node doesn't have a Privacy Field.

```
{album-id}?fields=name,id,privacy,photos.fields(id,privacy)

{
  "name": "Profile Pictures",
  "id": ...,
  "privacy": "everyone",
  "photos": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": ...
      },
      {
        "id": ...
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

The privacy for this album is "everyone", however I can change the privacy of individual pictures inside from within Facebook, so I don't know which ones are safe. There is no privacy fields on the pictures inside.

How can I tell which photos are public for these types of albums?

I'm using Facebook SDK for iOS and Android, targetting OpenGraph v2.5.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: File a documentation bug @ https://developers.facebook.com/bugs